# rostopic piping

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to do something with rostopic that may not be possible, though the documentation suggests it is, and it's possible I've just got bad syntax or XAML usage.  Using turtlesim, I'd like to *initially* do something simple on the command line, like:

```
while true; do echo '{linear: 0.0, angular: 1.0}'; sleep 1; done | rostopic pub -l turtle1/command_velocity turtlesim/Velocity
```

This doesn't seem to work, and I get no error messages of any sort.  Am I missing something?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/40524/rostopic-piping/) by [urgent](https://answers.ros.org/users/2971/urgent/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2012-08-03

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are trying to publish an unchanging message repeatedly, use the rate parameter (-r) for rostopic on the commandline:

```
rostopic pub -r 10 turtle1/command_velocity turtlesim/Velocity "{'linear':0.0, 'angular':1.0}"
```

This should publish a turtlesim/Velocity type msg to the turtle1/command_velocity topic at 10 Hz.

---

Originally posted by [pgrice](https://answers.ros.org/users/235/pgrice/) with karma: 196 on 2012-08-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2